# Java class only printing out text from previous save of text file

Tags: java, file-io, char

I'm trying to get my code to save a user input (char) to a text file, and return it in another class. The issue is, the other class is only printing out the previous version. For example, if 'e' is written to the text file, and then 'f' replaces the 'e', the class would still only print out 'e', but if I then replaced 'f' with 'g', 'f' would be the char printed.

This is the code that writes to the file

```
public void setChar(char charChoice)
{
    if (Character.isLetter(charChoice))
    {
        playableChar = charChoice; 
        String fileName = "temp.txt";
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try 
        {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            outputStream.println(playableChar);
            outputStream.close();
        } 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error, invalid input");
    }
}
```

and here is the code that reads from the file (we'll say it's in class Reader)

```
public char getTextFile()
{
    String fileName = "temp.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    String line = inputStream.nextLine();
    char playableChar = line.charAt(0);

    inputStream.close();
    return playableChar;
}
```

now when I call

```
char xyz = reader.getTextFile();
```

it will print out the char in the previous version of the file.

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

edit

```
public void change()
{
    boolean guess = true;
    while(Guess)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a desired character (A-Z): ");
        String x = keyboard.next();
        String xLower = x.toLowerCase();
        if ((Character.isLetter(x.charAt(0))) && (x.length() == 1)) 
        {
            char xChar = x.charAt(0);
            setChar(xChar);
            guess = false;
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a single letter between A and Z.");
        }
    }
}
```

edit 2

```
Reader reader = new Reader();
private char PLAYER = reader.getTextFile();
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you should be using:  `outputStream.append(playableChar);`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Just ran unit tests against your code, and it runs fine. The problem must be outside the code you pasted. Can you show us the code that calls these 2 methods.

Comment: can you add the code where you are using `setChar`?

Comment: The only thing odd that stands out to me would be the "Guess" field used in the while loop. It has a capital for the G, and the variable set has a lower case g. So, the loop will not break. Another odd thing is why the PLAYER field is a class field? It most likely should not be one.